# async function in useeffect get old prop

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

i have some code like:

```
let props.n default =1

    function consoleLog()
    {
        dispatch({n:2});
            useEffect(()=>
            {
                   async function c()
                   {
                     await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>setTimeout(() =>resolve(), 1500));
                     console.log(props.n);
                   }
                   c();
            },[]);
        return(null);
    }
```

I get the result is 1 , but not 2 , 
how can i use the new props but not the old props?

Comment: You need to add `n` as a dependency. Instead of having `[]` as a 2nd argument in `useEffect`, try to set `[props.n]`. This way, `useEffect` will run when `n` is updated. With `[]`, `isEffect` will only be run once when the component is mounted.

Answer (score 1):

ok, that's really tricky but you can use `useRef` to put some prop there

```
function A(props) {
  const storage = useRef();
  storage.current = props.some;
  useEffect(()=>  {
    async function c() {
      await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>setTimeout(() =>resolve(), 1500));
      console.log(storage.current.some);
    }
    c();
  },[]);
}
```

since `props` just a variable some function delayed in running that has access to first version of data does not have access to next version.

But I believe it may be more suitable way to achieve your final goal.